# Cloning github repo using git bash error

Tags: github, clone, git-bash

I am new to git and github. I recently forked  repo:

https://github.com/PieterKJ/ProgrammingAssignment2

Now I want to clone this repository in my working directory. So I use following command in git bash:

```
git clone https://github.com/PieterKJ/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
```

However, this gives me following error:

$ git clone https://github.com/PieterKJ/ProgrammingAssignment2.git
Cloning into 'ProgrammingAssignment2'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PieterKJ/ProgrammingAssignment2.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:/Users/PiKr/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/usr/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none

It would be really awesome if someone could help me out

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.  The first is to update your CAs on your computer (the GitHub certificate chain includes the newest ones from Mozilla).

The second is a temporary solution: use the following:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1 git clone 'https://github.com/PieterKJ/ProgrammingAssignment2.git'
```